# How to get original IP address of a client in java?

Tags: java

We can get client IP address from `Request` object as follows:

```
 String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

But, if the user is behind a proxy server or access your web server through a load balancer, the above code will get the IP address of the proxy server or load balancer server, not the original IP address of a client.

Comment: So this is a proxy, NAT etc for. No way to get the client IP(s) on the local network, if the client doesn't send it as payload.

Comment: The only way is to ask the client see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript-only

Comment: Why? and don't forget, ip adresses can be spoofed, and if it's routed via onion it's for intents and purposes impossible to trace back.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about HTTP requests, you may try the following:

```
String strForwardedFor = httpServletRequest.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
```

If the proxy sets this header, it should look like:

```
client-ip,proxy1-ip,proxy2-ip,...
```

Comment: Remember that this header can be easily spoofed. You can only trust the ones you know.  (See Shane Madden's answer in http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24197/is-it-possible-to-spoof-the-last-proxy-of-an-x-forwarded-for-header)